# a beginner's approach & confusion bash script

Tags: bash

I've started learning bash today, but I knew basics of javascript.

It would be very nice if anyone can point me at least a few advices on the code.

Because there are so many details in bash, I hope you won't be too harsh.

**Expected behavior**

The code is supposed:

- to set the value of a variable named 'charge' from the input files
- create a few directories and subdirectories based on the input files

**Concrete Example**

Let's say there is a mol2 file named `glucose-minus1.mol2`.

- I expect the code to set up a variable charge with value -1, so charge="-1". So you can see there is a translation from minus1 --> -1
  If the filename is 'wrong' the user should be notified "we can't find the charge value in the filename" or something like that.
- And to create a directory named `glucose-minus1` (without the
  extension) plus the 3 sub-directories "solv" "sin-solv" and "thermo".
  All this if the directories are do no exist already.

````
#!/bin/bash
touch "mol-minus1.mol2" "mol-minus2.mol2"
molecules=(*.mol2)
subdirs=("solv" "sin-solv" "thermo")


setCharge () {
        #input molfile
        #if it finds any chargeLabel in molfile, sets the charge value (and we use it later).
        chargeLabels=( "minus3" "minus2" "minus1" "cero" "plus1" "plus2" )
        charges=("-3" "-2" "-1" "0" "+1" "+2")
        echo "${chargeLabels[*]}"
        for index in "${!chargeLabels[@]}"
        do
                if [[ "$1" == *"${chargeLabels[index]}"* ]]
                then
                        charge="${charges[index]}"
                        echo "$charge"
                else
                        echo "Im not setting charges..."
                        continue
                fi
        done
}

createDir(){
        #pass dir as an argument.
        if [ ! -d "$1" ]
        then
                mkdir "$1"
        else
                printf " %s is already there " "$1"
        fi
}
for mol in "${molecules[@]}"
do
        [ -f "$mol" ] || exit 0
        #sets the carge variable to a value included in molfile.
        echo "$mol"
        setCharge "$mol"
        #acreate molecule directory if not there.
        IFS="." read -ra splitted <<< "$mol"
        if [[ ! -d "${splitted[0]}" ]]
        then
                mkdir "${splitted[0]}"
                printf "directory %s has been created. Molecule charge is %s" "${splitted[0]}" "$charge"
        else
                printf "directory %s already exists. Molecule charge is %s" "${splitted[0]}" "$charge"
                continue
        fi

        #create subdirectories if not there.
        cd "${splitted[0]}" || printf "No directory with name %s" "${splitted[0]}" && exit 0
        for dir in "${subdirs[@]}" #create subdirs if not there.
        do
                createDir "$dir"
        done
        cd '../' #single quotes for string literals.
        cp "$mol" "${splitted[0]}/sin-solv/"
        #python -c'import flexo_api.py; flexo_api.flexo("$)'
done

```
````